# How do we convert 2018-12-31 as Week 1 of 2019 in SQL?

Tags: sql

Using `CONCAT(TO_CHAR(T.order_create_date,'yyyy')," ",WEEKOFYEAR(T.order_create_date))` returns `2018-12-31` as `2018-1`.

Comment: (1) Please define what you mean by "week".  (2) Please tag your question with a single database.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=week-of-year-in-sql-confusing

Comment: `to_char(order_create_date, 'iyyy-iw')` maybe? https://rextester.com/ZMSQ95102

Answer (score 0):

The first week of each year starts on the first Monday on or before January 4 of that year, so that the year begins from December 28 of the prior year through January 4 of the current year.

SELECT(DATEPART(dy,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',@SomeDate)/7*7,'17530104'))+6)/7;

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer. Thanks